# How to disable horizontal scrolling in an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, mobile

I'm doing an animation-on-scroll page. At the moment, I'm optimizing it for mobile devices.

In case an element is bigger than the actual screen (e.g. bigger than a mobile screen), you're able to scroll in that element (e.g. you're able to scroll horizontally in an image). How can I block that?
I've already found out that the e.g. actual x-scroll-position doesn't change when scrolling through an image horizontally.

Because of the animation, I'm not able to set any elements position to relative. Overflow-x: hidden doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: Thank you, dale landry's answer already answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `overflow-x:` to `hidden` or `overflow: hidden` on the parent element to hide the view of the scroll bar for your image element which will be on the parents ***border-box***. Then you can move your image element around `relative` to the parent element by positioning it using `position: absolute;`.

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.parent img {
  position: absolute;
  left: -220px;
  top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/06/05/18/22/nature-2374798_640.jpg">
</div>

<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/06/05/18/22/nature-2374798_640.jpg">
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked great!
This does mean that overflow: hidden only concerns the child of the element it is applied to, doesn't it? Also: position: absolute then means absolute but (relative) from the parent element, am I right?

Comment: `overflow: hidden` is going to set the behavior of the elements overflow it is applied to. So in my example it hides the scrolling overflow of the parent element, which is the element the image is nested into. `position: absolute` means that the element it is applied to will be removed from the normal flow of the DOM, ***document object model*** and this opens the ability to use positioning properties like ***top***, ***left***, ***right*** and/or ***bottom***, this also means it will be ***positioned*** to the closest ***relatively*** positioned element that has ***position: relative;***